# Hide and show elements using one function and number argument

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
function gato(n){
    if(n == 1){
        document.getElementById("A" + n).style.display="block";
    }
    if(n == 2){
        document.getElementById("B" + n).style.display="block";
    }
}
</script>

<body style="width:auto">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="cuadro1" onClick="gato(1)">
        <div style="display:none" id="A1" onClick="gato(2)"> <img src="images/x.png" alt=""/> </div>
        <div style="display:none" id="B2" onClick="gato(1)"> <img src="images/o.png" alt=""/> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is supposed to happen is: when you click the div class `cuadro1` then the div with id `A1` is going to be displayed, then when you click that div(id `A1`) then the div id `B2` is going to be displayed. then you can click that div id `B2` and go back to div id `A1`.

I believe the problem lies in that you have to un-display id `A` before displaying id `B2` with `document.getElementById("B2").style.display="none";`  but I just can't get it to work.

Comment: Please use better title next time. Judging from your post, you are not incappable of writing normal sentence, so do us all that favor. Other people might find this on google if you use good title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're a beginner, I also made changes to your design:

#### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="cuadro1" onClick="gato(1)">
        <h1>Click here to show #1</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div style="display:none" id="A1" onClick="gato(2, this)"> <h2>DIV#1</h2> </div>
        <div style="display:none" id="A2" onClick="gato(1, this)"> <h2>DIV#2</h2> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I put `#A1` and `#A2` from `class="cuadro1"`. This is because click events *bubble* from the clicked element to his parents. So when anyone clicks `A1` or `A2` the `cuadro1` is also clicked. That means `A1` would be allways shown.

I also renamed `B2` to `A2` for convenience.

#### Javascript

```
functiongato(n, clickedDiv) {
   // Hide the div that was clicked
   if(clickedDiv!=null)
       clickedDiv.style.display = "none";
   // Change whatever ID is given
   document.getElementById("A" + n).style.display="block";
}
```

To save ourselves time, we can use `this` refference in `onclick` to hide div that was clicked. The `clickedDiv!=null` allows you to pass nothing if you don't want to hide clicked div. Since names are now `A1` and `A2`, `if` statement is no longer needed.

Here's a test: https://jsfiddle.net/1zojdvt0/

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to accomplish this, using css.  Add/remove a class from your elements and use CSS styling based on class to hide the div contents.

Javascript:

```
function gato(n, clicked){
   if(clicked) {
       clicked.classList.add('hidden');
   }
   var showElem = (n == 1 ? "A1" : "B2");
   document.getElementById(showElem).classList.remove('hidden');
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="cuadro1" onClick="gato(1, null)">Click Me
    <div class="hidden" id="A1" onClick="gato(2, this)">A1  </div>
    <div class="hidden" id="B2" onClick="gato(1, this)">B2  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden { display:none;}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1h3zukp1/)